# App store account sign in

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

When I open the App Store on my iPhone, it opens my Australian account by default. How can I change the settings so it opens my US account (which I do own legally).

Comment: Mine always stays logged in so I'm not sure why you're experiencing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Click to open the App Store,  sliding to the bottom of the page, you can see your AU account, click on it, select `log out`.Then you can log in the US account.

Comment: Thanks vanemu.   Your name sounds Dutch Australian to me !?

Answer (score 0):

Go to 'Settings < Store' op your iPhone and scroll to the bottom of the page. There you'll see your Apple ID. By tapping on it, you get some options:

[image]

If you choose to log out, you can log in with your US account and it will open the Store app by default with your US account.